# 4 seconds delay using gates or flipflops

Tags: digital-logic, design, schematics, flipflop, delay

In my design , I want to add delay of 4 seconds to rising edge of input Vin.

I tried using below circuit , but problem is, in my setup, i am not able to see 4 seconds delay. Though I have checked below circuit externally. Reason might be change in impedance ( change RC when connected in my setup )

[image: CKT]

Is there any other way to generate delay using hardware (of 4 seconds approx )?

**PS. I want to do this with hardware only. And also RC delay is not working in my set up and looking for other options such as gates or flipflops**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a 555 circuit instead.

Comment: Your timer should work. What values are R1 / C1? What type of AND gate is it? "*Though I have checked below circuit externally. Reason might be change in impedance ...*" What do you mean by this? Have you something else hooked onto C1?

Comment: R is 1M and C is 4.7 uF, delay is 3.3 sec which is ok for me. IC 555 is not useful in my case since it requires negative edge followed by rising edge to switch output. Gate is 74LS00  Nand followed by 7404 Not Gate since I dont have AND gate. Not Output connected to IC 555.

Comment: The 74LS00 is probably the problem. That's why I asked about the type of gate. See @stretch's answer below.

Comment: which IC can we use?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that pin A is always high. The 74LS00 needs to have hundreds of
microamps sunk by an input to consider it a low. The current from pin A charges the capacitor and it stays charged. You should use a CMOS IC, preferably a Schmitt Trigger.

Comment: Which CMOS IC you are talking about? CMOS AND or Schmitt Trigger, can you recommend me any ic?

Comment: If A is high always , it will pass B input which is original signal without delay .. so it seems correct please suggest which IC 's to be used as alternative for 74LS00 and 7404? Also when checked externally it worked, how it worked? Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit can work but first off all you should know the caracteristics of your design. First off all, we have a simple formula "Vc = Vsupply*(1-e^(-t/RC)" that gives us voltage across the capacitor (Vc) due to time. Depending on the type of your logic gate (CMOS or TTL), there is some difference between the logic level (high-low) voltages.

- If you are using CMOS gate, your setup should reach at least 3.5V level at the 4. second.
- If you are using TTL gate, your setup should reach at least 2V level at the 4. second.

You can easly find out your R and C values using the formula. You can use electrolytic capacitors if you need more farads.

Comment: He said that his RC setup is not working,  probably because he has some other components Hooked up with them.

Comment: R is 1M and C is 4.7 uF, delay is 3.3 sec which is ok for me. I tried using below circuit , but problem is, in my setup, i am not able to see 4 seconds delay. Though I have checked below circuit externally.